# c pthread global variables - no write access / no update

Tags: c

I have a problem writing global variables in pthreads.
Some variables defined in the head of my code ->

```
int iPlcWriteReal;
```

I created some functions and called them over the pthreads.

In the Main the threads are called ->

```
iThreadResult = pthread_create(&threadWeb, NULL, pThreadWebserver, &fTest);
pthread_join(threadWeb, NULL);
```

The problem is when I write the global `int` from any Thread - the Value will be not updated in the own thread and not in the other threads (iPlcWriteReal = 34;).

There are 3 Threads and every threads has a wihile(1) loop inside->
Read Data / Webserver / Archive Data

With the Mutex function lock&unlock I had no success.

With Pointer & `malloc` I also had no luck.
I passed also a Pointer trough the Threads - the Address always was the right one - but the value was not be updated.

The communication to the global data is working when I don't use the while(1) - loop - are there any problems when I use any loop in pthreads with writing global values ?
Maybe Sync / Update functions ?

Comment: And that's why concurrent programming is really, really hard...

Comment: @KerrekSB - It is not that difficult - the female population do it all the time! Nag, Winge and wipe a babies bottom at the same time! With any luck I will get spanked at the same time!!!!

Comment: honestly, how do you think that we are supposed to reply to that question?

Comment: I think you'd have a greater chance of getting actual help if you posted your full code. Or better yet a very stripped down version of your code that showed the essential bits. Like: a global variable, a couple of pthreads accessing it, expected results, actual results. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

i found my problem-> the fork() was the problem.

The Fork() makes a copy from the his own process and he is using the actual values from the share/global data.
From the Fork-Process you can not directly access global data.

Instead of a fork i made a pthread inside a pthread - and now its working.

Thx